# Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ when $y=(\ln x)^x$+$(\sin^{-1}x)^{\sin x}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Find ${\dfrac {dy}{dx}}$

$$y=(\ln x)^x+(\sin^{-1}x)^{\sin x} , \quad x\in \left(0,\;\frac \pi2\right) \setminus \{1\}$$

My Approach:

$${\frac {d}{dx}}(e^{xlnlnx})+{\frac {d}{dx}}(e^{sinxln(arcsinx)})$$
$$= e^{xlnlnx}.{\frac {d}{dx}}(xlnlnx)+e^{sinxln(arcsinx)}.{\frac {d}{dx}}(sinxln(arcsinx))$$
$$=e^{xlnlnx}.(1.lnlnx+x{\frac {1}{lnx}})+e^{sinxln(arcsinx)}.cosx.ln(arcsinx)+sinx.{\frac {1}{arcsinx}}$$

There is something wrong I know, but I am not an experts and that's why posted here. Any help would be appreciated.

Second approach:

First part:
$$y= lnx^x$$
$$lny = ln(lnx)^x$$
$${\frac {d}{dx}}lny = {\frac {d}{dx}}[ln(lnx)^x]$$
$${\frac 1y}{\frac {dy}{dx}} = {\frac {d}{dx}}[xln(lnx)]$$
$${\frac {dy}{dx}} = [ln(lnx)+{\frac {1}{lnx}}]lnx^x$$

Second part:
$$y = (sin^{-1}x)^{sinx}$$
$$lny = ln(sin^{-1}x)^{sinx}$$
$${\frac {d}{dx}}lny = {\frac {d}{dx}}[sinx.ln(sin^{-}x)]$$
$${\frac 1y}{\frac {dy}{dx}} = {\frac {d}{dx}}sinx.ln(sin^{-1}x)+sinx.{\frac {d}{dx}}[ln(sin^{-1}x)]$$
$${\frac {dy}{dx}} = [cosx.ln(sin^1x)+{\frac {sinx}{sin^-1x(\sqrt {1-x^2})}}].sin^{-1}x^sinx$$

Running into an endless loop... any help?

Comment: Use log differentiation to find the derivatives of $(\ln)^x$ and $(\sin^{-1})^{\sin x}$ respectively, then add them together.

Comment: Please read my edit, to check if it is what you intended to post. Note: $]a, b[ = (a, b)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: you can transform it to exponent form $$y={ e }^{ x\ln { \ln { x }  }  }+{ e }^{ \sin { x } \ln { \left( \arcsin { x }  \right)  }  }$$

Comment: tried your approach. any suggestion on next step?

Comment: Have you tried the chain rule?